# How to enable Facebook Notifications without hiding App Page

Tags: facebook

In order to trigger the FB notification when someone receives an app request to get our mobile game, we had to enable a Canvas Page.  But changing this caused the canvas page to **replace** our Fan Page (ie "App Page") in the search results when someone searches the name of our game from within FB.

So either our invited facebookers won't know they've been invited, or our Facebook fans can't find our fan page.  Hopefully I'm missing something and there's a way to have both?

(This problem could be mitigated a bit if we were able to include a link to our App Page from our Canvas Page, but we haven't been able to make that work either.)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you break out of your canvas iframe with your link?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/" target="_top">My Fan Page</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Nate, that's helpful, and makes this problem a little smaller.